# AWS DynamoDB query error for between

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use an query in my AWS Lambda to filter entries from DynamoDB. I want to receive entries which are between two numbers. My database looks like this:

[image: Database Schema]

And these are my params for the query:

```
var params = {
        TableName: "tableName",
        KeyConditions: {
            'date': {
                ComparisonOperator: "BETWEEN",
                AttributeValueList: [30, 100]
            }
        }
    };

    docClient.query(params, function(err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            _response = buildOutput(500, err);
            return callback(_response, null);
        }
        _response = buildOutput(200, resp);
        return callback(null, _response);
    });
```

I'm getting the following error message but I don't know what is missing at the params

> response: {"message":"Query condition missed key schema element: id"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Query API, you need to mention the hash key in the `KeyConditions`. As per your table definition, it looks like `id` is the hash key attribute of the table. Hash key is the mandatory attribute to use Query API. You should provide the value of hash key i.e. `Id` in order to use Query API.

If you don't know hash key, you may need to use **Scan API** to get the data.

Again, you can't use Query API without knowing the hash key of the table. Even, creating the index may not help if you don't know the hash key of the index.

[Query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)